# Graphql create new type from two types?

Tags: graphql

I am trying to setup some types for tables in a database, one for `city` and one for `vendor`. When I do a join on the tables I get them both back, so I thought that I could do a `union CityVendor = City | Vendor` and say that is the return type for the `nearby_vendors`. The types look like this:

```
  type City {
    zip: String
    zone: String
    city: String
    state: String
    latitude: Float
    longitude: Float
    distance: Float
  }

  type Vendor {
    vendor_id: Int
    zip: String
    name: String
    address: String
    avatar: String
    description: String
    private: Boolean
  }

  union CityVendor = City | Vendor

  type Query {
    nearby_vendors(longitude: Float!, latitude: Float!, distance: Int): [CityVendor]
  }
```

However, when executed, I get this error:

> Cannot query field "name" on type "CityVendor". Did you mean to use an inline fragment on "Vendor"?

Is there a way I can combine two types in graphql to make a single type so that this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write it with inline fragments as it says. You may need to modify the variables you pass in, I can't see the whole context but it needs to look something like this:

```js
query Foo($bar: String) {
  nearby_vendors(bar: $bar) {
    # these fields exist in both City and Vendor
    zip

    ... on City {
      # only these fields exist on City
      longitude
    }

    ... on Vendor {
      # only exists on Vendor
      avatar
    }
}
```